# Get array of items from phpAdmin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

In my phpAdmin I have a list of arrays that I need to be able to access in php Wordpress.

I need to get these two arrays and the variables associated with them but I can't find anywhere how to access this type of information.

Essentially I would like to loop through all these items and match one of their variables with the ID of specific posts - I have the post part.

```
wp_learnpress_sections
wp_learnpress_section_items
```

Basically the item_type is an `lp_lesson` which is a custom post type. I am able to grab all the posts from wp_posts so I figured I would be able to grab these other arrays?

Edit:

[image: This is the items (minus the sessions) that are displayed on the side panel along with wp_post.]

[image: Variables I need to access in my theme function from wp_learnpress_sections]

[image: Variables I need to access from wp_learnpress_section_items]

My theme function. This works for all the posts. However, I want to be able to find out which section_id a post belongs to.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'win_9388244_format_lp_lesson' );

function win_9388244_format_lp_lesson() {
  //Get post type of lp_lesson
        $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'lp_lesson',
         'numberposts' => 99999
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpk_icon_text', 'Test' ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is for administering your DB - not PHP arrays or any of that sort.

Comment: show all info, which may help. how do you saved that arrays in the db? what is the structure of table, where you serve arrays? where you defined the `the variables associated with them`? where do you want access( from which file ) to that arrays?

Comment: My apologies. I added more information on what I am trying to accomplish (if it's possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full function that does it:

```
function win_9388244_format_lp_lesson() {
  //Get post type of lp_lesson
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lp_lesson',
    'numberposts' => 99999
  );
  $posts = get_posts($args);
  global $wpdb;
  $sections = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT section_item_id, section_id, item_id FROM wp_learnpress_section_items", ARRAY_A );
  $items = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT section_course_id, section_id FROM wp_learnpress_sections", ARRAY_A );
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $lesson_id = $post->ID;
    foreach($sections as $section) {
      if($section['item_id'] == $lesson_id) {
        $currentSection = $section['section_id'];
        foreach($items as $item) {
          if ($item['section_id'] == $currentSection) {
            $course = $item['section_course_id'];
            //switch $course with predefined variables for courses
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```